# Template specialization of a function inside a templated class C++

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Below is the code

```
template <class T>
class Demo
{
public:
    T var;
    Demo(T a)
    {
        var = a;
    }
    void PrintDemo()
    {
        cout << "In generic PrintDemo " << var << endl;
        cout << "Var is " << var << endl;
    }
    template<typename int>
    void PrintDemo()
    {
        cout << "In int PrintDemo " << var << endl;
        cout << "Var is " << var << endl;
    }
};
```

When I compile this code, I get below error:

```
main.cpp:18:23: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘int’
   18 |     template<typename int>
```

Can some one help me out to understand the error?

This is my requirement. But I am not able to compile it.

Comment: you have a class template so you need to specialize the class

Comment: Can you explain, in your own words, what you expect `template<typename int>` to do? What is the results of that? And what does specialization have to do with this?

Comment: See dupe: [Specialize member function of class template using C++20 concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71025802/specialize-member-function-of-class-template-using-c20-concepts) and [Partial template specialization on class methods using enable_if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74323336/partial-template-specialization-on-class-methods-using-enable-if)

Answer (score 1):

`void PrintDemo()` is not a template, there is nothing to specialize. If you want to call specific function based on *class* template parameter, you can use `concept` to achieve it. (with `c++20`)

```
template <class T>
class Demo
{
public:
    T var;
    Demo(T a = 0)
    {
        var = a;
    }
    void PrintDemo()
    {
        cout << "In generic PrintDemo " << var << endl;
        cout << "Var is " << var << endl;
    }

    void PrintDemo() requires std::same_as<T,int>
    {
        cout << "In int PrintDemo " << var << endl;
        cout << "Var is " << var << endl;
    }
};
```

---

or you can use `constexpr` `if` in c++17

Answer (score 1):

Besides the examples given, another way is to use `std::enable_if<>`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/utility.hpp>

template <class T>
class Demo
{
public:
    T var;
    Demo(T a)
    {
        var = a;
    }

    boost::disable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>>
    PrintDemo()
    {
        cout << "In generic PrintDemo " << var << endl;
        cout << "Var is " << var << endl;
    }

    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>>
    PrintDemo()
    {
        cout << "In int PrintDemo " << var << endl;
        cout << "Var is " << var << endl;
    }
};
```

In the generic case, when you have a return type, you might specify it as the second type argument of `std::enable_if` / `std::disable_if` (e.g.     `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>, bool>` for a function returning `bool` value).

If you don't want to include boost for this, you can also define `disable_if` simply as:

```
template<bool B, class T = void>
struct disable_if {};
 
template<class T>
struct disable_if<false, T> { typedef T type; };

template<bool B, typename T = void>
using disable_if_t = typename disable_if<B, T>::type;
```

Comment: `disable_if` ? Does this exist? Even if yes, this expands to `int void PrintDemo() { ...`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yep, it's boost, not std, but it exists and expands as expected: OP wanted an int an a non-int version of `PrintDemo()`.

Comment: ok, but i think you mean `boost::disable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>> PrintDemo()` rather than `boost::disable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>> void PrintDemo()`. Your non-int overload has return type `void void` ...

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Ah yes, typo, sorry for that. Thanks for spotting, fixed.

Comment: would be nice to add the includes. Especially with boost i find it extremely hard to browse documentation to find in which header something is declared

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Added, also added a definition for that - in case someone doesn't want to bring boost in as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specialise only one function within a class template, as you have to specialise the class template as a whole:

```cpp
template <>
class Demo<int> {
public:
    int var;
    Demo(int a) {
        var = a;
    }

    void PrintDemo() {
        std::cout << "In generic PrintDemo " << var << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Var is " << var << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Alternatively you can specialise the function outside of the class declaration:

```cpp
template<>
void Demo<int>::PrintDemo() {
    std::cout << "In generic PrintDemo " << var << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Var is " << var << std::endl;
}
```